# Azure: programmatic way to download usage details?

Tags: azure

Is there an automated way to pull usage details from Azure for a given subscription?  I'm using the pyazure library for service/deployment management, but can't find any API references anywhere for billing/usage information.

Answer (score 2):

There is not currently a billing or usage API. Its been asked for and discussed extensively, so I believe we will see it eventually. But currently, there is no ETA.

Comment: Bummer, was hoping I'd missed it.  OK, I'm solving this by polling the deployment status every few minutes (yuk :-).  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Brent's answer: If you want details on Storage usage, that *is* programmatically available: You can collect information on individual objects as well as aggregated hourly rollups.

More information on Storage Analytics is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343268.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

All,

We have just released two Azure Billing APIs (Azure Usage API and Azure RateCard API) which can give you API level access to your consumption and the rates at which we will charge you, and this can enable you to track your charges.

A few helpful pointers for you are listed below:

High-level article talking about the Azure Billing APIs and how it aims to solve the IT Financial management use-cases: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-usage-rate-card-overview/

Scott Guthrie's blog post talking about the Azure Billing APIs: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-azure-billing-apis-available

Hope this helps.

Moinak